# Collaborative Browsing using HTML5 and websockets

Tags: html, websocket

I want to share whatever I am browsing to appear on another tab. How is it possible to achieve this using HTML5 and Websockets ?

Answer (score 1):

Websockets is a bit overkill for this.  Just use sessionStorage with an event listener:

When the url changes, sink the url into some session storage key and then have the tabs listen for changes using something like:

```
function onStorageEvent(storageEvent){
   alert("storage event");
}
window.addEventListener('storage', onStorageEvent, false);
```